# Altium - refusing to load footprint

Tags: altium

I made a custom Footprint, whenever I try to link to a schematic library, Altium refuse and just pop a random footprint instead.

What are the reasons that could lead altium to refuse to load a footprint?

Here the image of the footprint:

[image]

Comment: It's kinda vague problem definition. Any error messages?

Comment: maybe the same unique ID/library reference as an existing footprint?

Comment: There is no error message; i will look into KyranF comment

Comment: How are you trying to link them? Are you in the SCH Library panel? Double-clicking on the part number, going to the bottom right under "Models", clicking "Add..." and browsing for your footprint?

Comment: @KyranF you can post your comment as an answer, I will valid it. Indeed 2 component in 2 footprint library had the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of this issue is that the footprint you made and are trying to add to the existing library already has a footprint of the same unique ID or library reference name. This cannot work, as every footprint must have a unique name.

I think it is only on a per-library basis; you can have another library of footprints with the same footprint names as the other library, and it will still allow you to use both libraries at the same time.

Comment: Good call! I had this problem before but couldn't remember how I fixed it.